EmitSound Problem
I want to emit several sounds with an indication of each name according to their duration times. My code is below. But sounds and updating information in a grid don't synchronize. I'm looking for an exact way to work as I expected.
Preparation :
codes= #<>"4"&/@RotateLeft[CharacterRange["A","G"],2];
notes= SoundNote/@AppendTo[codes,"C5"];
  (* {SoundNote["C4"], SoundNote["D4"], SoundNote["E4"], SoundNote["F4"], 
SoundNote["G4"], SoundNote["A4"], SoundNote["B4"], SoundNote["C5"]}  *) 
times= Range[Length[notes]]/3;
  (*  {1/3, 2/3, 1, 4/3, 5/3, 2, 7/3, 8/3}  *)  
sounds = Thread[Sound[notes, times]];

Dynamic Version:
DynamicModule[{i=0},
    Dynamic[Refresh[If[i == Length[notes],i=1,i+=1];
        Column[{EmitSound[sounds[[i]]],
                Grid[{{"Note","Duration"},{codes[[i]],times[[i]]}}, 
                        Alignment->{Center,Center},ItemSize->{Automatic,{Automatic,2}},Frame->All],
                Pause[times[[i]]]}],                     
    TrackedSymbols:>{},UpdateInterval-> 0]],DynamicUpdating->False]

Animate Version:
Animate[Column[{EmitSound[sounds[[i]]];
                Grid[{{"Note","Duration"}, {codes[[i]],times[[i]]}}, 
                     Alignment->{Center,Center},ItemSize->{Automatic,{Automatic,2}},Frame->All],
                Pause[times[[i]]]}],
       {i,1,Length[notes],1},AnimationRunning->False]


Does it suit you if – in dynamic version – you just remove the Pause, and set UpdateInterval -> 2?

@Domen Your modification achieves synchronization and fixes the updating interval.
However, I want the updating information in a grid to occur immediately after each sound duration.
